# Textbox Textchanged not working after backspacing

Tags: vb.net

my vb.net Textbox's Textchanged event not working after backspacing.
So i have a text box which user can input value on it. 
Then this textbox will search through sql using textchanged event.
For example, if i input **HUM**, it will return value to list view like this:

```
HUMAN
HUMANITY
I AM HUMAN
Etc
```

The problem is, if i type it wrong like **HUM,** (with comma) and i backspace the comma, the query is not working anymore. The list view shows empty list. 
So what do i need to do to fix this backspacing issue?

Here is the code :

```
Private Sub txtString1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtString1.TextChanged
   query2 = "SELECT fnID, string1, output, FROM quotes where string1 like '%" & txtString1.Text & "%' order by fnID asc"
   Call FillList2()
End Sub

Private Sub FillList2()
    With lvDaftarOutput
        .Clear()
        .View = View.Details
        .GridLines = True
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .Columns.Add("ID", 0)
        .Columns.Add("String1", 0)
        .Columns.Add("Output", 150)

    End With

        Call FillListView(lvDaftarOutput, GetData(query2))

End Sub
```

It's all working fine, except when i backspace the value on the textbox.

Comment: You can restrict characters like `,` in textbox's key press event...Does your textbox needs to be allow alphabets only?... BTW you should show the code written in `textchanged` event

Comment: Hi, added the code. Please kindly check it. Thanks

Comment: also, the textbox allow all kind of text. so when i enter HUMM, and i want to delete 1 M, it also not working.

Comment: Just for clarification. Your txtString1_TextChanged sub handles changes made to the TextBox called txtUsernameTransaksi . Is this intentional? I wonder, because you make no reference to txtUsernameTransaksi in any of th e code you're showing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the method you build your query.

Try to build it like this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE [TableA] SET ColumnA=@ColumnA WHERE ID=@ID", Conn)

cmd.CommandText = "select * from customer where id=?id";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id",CustomerIDValue);
```

Comment: As above, this shoould be in the comments. Not an answer . Cheers

Comment: I'm sorry. @ TE, have you tried to use a masked textbox?
Is it necessary , to allow "," in your query?